# Not able to install Groovy Eclipse plugin in Eclipse 2022-12

Tags: eclipse, groovy, m2eclipse, groovy-eclipse

I haven't installed the Groovy Eclipse plugin for a while because I mostly did not need it anymore.  However, I'm now looking at one project that I need this for.

I'm using Eclipse 2022-12.

When I attempt to install the latest Groovy plugin from the Marketplace, it simply says that both "Eclipse Groovy Development Tools" and "Groovy-Eclpse M2E integration" will "not be installed", but "Groovy Compiler 3.0" and "Groovy Compiler 4.0" WILL be installed.  This clearly is not very useful.  It doesn't say WHY it won't install the main tools.

It says the requested version is "4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE".

**Update**:

This is the dialog that I get, and the ONLY dialog that I get:
[image: plugin installation dialog]

**Update**:

After realizing that I should have selected "Show Original Error", this is what it gave me:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration 4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse.feature.feature.group 4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Groovy m2e integration 4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse 4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.9.1,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration 4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse.feature.feature.group 4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse [4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE,4.8.0.v202212311456-e2212-RELEASE]
```

This looks like a missing m2e artifact.

**Update**:

I attempted this installation of GroovyEclipse from the MarketPlace client (v4.8.0.RELEASE). Apparently that version is not compatible with 2022-12, so I used the update site specifically for 2022-12, https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.26 , which I got from https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki#releases . Unfortunately, the result was exactly the same. I clicked on "Show original error" and the error message was identical, character by character.

Comment: Show us the message. Was there a details panel, or maybe another text panel showing why?

Comment: Generally, when I say "simply says", I mean that is literally all that it says. I have edited the post with the single dialog that it presents when I attempt this installation. It gives me no other information. There is nothing in the error log about this.

Comment: Choose _Show original error and build my own solution_ to get more details.

Comment: I think the 2022-12 is not mature yet. Use 2022-09

Comment: @howlger , duh, I should have realized that. Updated.

Comment: According to the error message, the Groovy plugin you tried to install is not ready for Eclipse m2e 2.x which is contained in Eclipse 2022-12 and 2022-09. It requires m2e 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than 2.0.0 (`[1.9.1,2.0.0)`). Did you use the update site [`https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.26`](https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.26)? See https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki#releases

Comment: I did not. I've been in the habit of assuming the entry in the marketplace client is the one that works. That's what I used. I'll try using the update site. Unfortunately, the result is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: @injecteer , can you clarify your statement?  Are you referring to 2022-12 in general, or the GroovyEclipse plugin for 2022-12?

Comment: I tried installing the GDT on 2022-12 a month ago and it failed. Not exactly sure why, but from my experience, the Groovy Plugin is not yet available on eclipse 2022-12 repo.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy Eclipse 4.8.0 has two issues with Eclipse 2022-12.

1. If you install a packaged release, it is not possible to patch JDT Core plugin.  https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1425
2. (As you have noticed) m2e 2.x made breaking API changes.  You can install m2e 1.x or ... Groovy Eclipse 4.9.0 has made the necessary changes.  https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1405

Comment: Are there different variants of Groovy Eclipse 4.8.0 for different versions of the Eclipse platform/JDT provided via different update sites?

Comment: @howlger Yes, there is a separate update site for each version of Eclipse.  https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki#snapshots